# Tokenize a string into a list of strings, dependent on set of rules

Tags: string, haskell, compiler-construction

I have a string that needs to be tokenized into a list with the following rules:

- The '(' and ')' brackets
- A number with a possible decimal point
- Operators (+, / , *, >=, etc.)
- An identifier that starts with a letter and rest of the string can be letters or numbers

To do this I have created the above rules as finite state machines in Haskell code:

```
data FsaState = R | Q -- start state: Q; success state R;
  deriving Show
```

Input:

```
tokenize “( (23.5+age) ∗ (20.99+adres))”
```

Output:

```
[ “(”, “ ”, “(”, “23.5”, “+”, “age”, “)”, “ ”, “∗”, “ ”, “(”, “20.99”, “+”, “adres”, “)”, “)” ]
```

(maybe filter out the strings with only whitespace)

How should I begin? I am stuck in the imperative mindset as Haskell is not my main language.

Comment: Do you have anything against using an existing lexer like [Alex](https://www.haskell.org/alex/)? What about using a parsing library (like `megaparsec`, `attoparsec`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, I do this more for the learning experience and get a better grasp on Haskell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to represent a state machine is with a fold. Here’s the type of `foldl'` from `Data.List`, a *strict left fold*:

```
foldl' :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

This type is pretty general, so it may help to see it specialised, with `t ~ []` and `a ~ Char`:

```
foldl' :: (b -> Char -> b) -> b -> [Char] -> b
```

(Also recall that `type String = [Char]`.)

So `foldl' step start input` will run the `step` function on each character of the `input`, beginning from the `start` state, and return the final state. We can introduce a type representing the possible states of the machine, as you started to do in your question:

```
data State
  = StartState
  | NameState String
  | IntegerState String
  | DecimalState String
  | OperatorState String
  | …
```

However, our `step` function can’t just be of type `State -> Char -> State`, because we *also* want to accumulate a list of tokens as output. We can just use a pair of the state and the accumulator:

```
step :: (State, [Token]) -> Char -> (State, [Token])
```

(For the sake of simplicity, I’ll assume `type Token = String`, but in reality you would probably want to use an algebraic data type, e.g., `data Token = LeftParen | RightParen | Name String | Integer Int | …`.)

So the basic structure so far is:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List (foldl')

data State = …

tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize input = reverse $ snd $ foldl' step (StartState, []) input
  where
    step :: (State, [Token]) -> Char -> (State, [Token])
```

(We use `reverse` at the end because we’ll be accumulating tokens by prepending them to the list (O(1)) rather than appending (O(n)).)

Now you can proceed by simply filling in the cases—`step` defines the transitions between states in the machine. When we want to emit a token, we return a new list of tokens:

```
step (StartState, tokens) '(' = (StartState, "(" : tokens)
step (StartState, tokens) ')' = (StartState, ")" : tokens)
```

And when we want to perform state transitions, we return a new state:

```
step (StartState, tokens) char

  -- Whitespace is ignored, looping back to the start state.
  | isSpace char = (StartState, tokens)

  -- Letters cause a transition to the “name” state.
  | isLetter char = (NameState [char], tokens)

  -- Digits, to the “integer” state.
  | isDigit char = (IntegerState [char], tokens)

  -- And so on.
  | char `elem` "+-*/^" = (OperatorState [char], tokens)
  | …
```

Then it’s just a matter of implementing the transitions for all the other states. To make this easier, turning on `-Wall` will produce warnings about cases you haven’t handled.

For example, here’s how you might implement the `NameState` transitions:

```
step (NameState name, tokens) char
  | isLetter char || isDigit char = (NameState (char : name), tokens)
  | otherwise = step (StartState, reverse name : tokens) char
```

When we get a letter or digit, we accumulate it in the `NameState`; when we get something else, we emit the token and return to the `StartState`. But note that we don’t simply say `otherwise = (StartState, reverse name : tokens)`, because this would discard the character! Instead we *retry* the current character in the new state by calling `step` again.

I’ll leave it to you to figure out how to handle the end of the input; hint: there’s something we’ve forgotten to check after the fold is complete.

This approach is rather limited; if you want to add monadic effects, such as reporting parse errors with `Either String [Token]`, then you may find it unwieldy. At that point, I would recommend looking into how monadic parsing libraries work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your message, it greatly helped me, but I cannot find what is missing in the tokenize function. And I don't understand how you use reverse for everything. Things are in the wrong order.

Comment: @LouisHu: I accidentally wrote `foldl' step StartState` when I meant `foldl' step (StartState, [])`—the initial list of tokens is empty. Instead of `snd`, which ignores the final state, you could write a function such as `end :: (State, [Token]) -> [Token]` which defines what to do when the end of the string is reached in each state, e.g.: `end (NameState name, tokens) = reverse name : tokens`. I use `reverse` because, when accumulating characters/tokens, it’s more efficient to *prepend* to a list (`x : xs`) than to append (`xs ++ [x]`), but you can use the latter if you find it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably define a a token data type (`data Token = ...`) if you are worried about efficiency. That said, here is a minimal tokenizer that does roughly what you are looking for. It works (tail) recursively, munching off a token (or whitespace) for every recursive call.

I've chosen to discard whitespace instead of making it into a token.

```
import Data.Char

tokenize :: String -> [String]
tokenize "" = []
tokenize (c:cs)
  | isSpace c = tokenize cs
  | isAlpha c = let (i,cs') = span isAlphaNum cs in (c : i) : tokenize cs'
  | isDigit c = let (n,cs') = span isDigit cs
                in case cs' of
                     ('.':cs'') -> let (m,cs''') = span isDigit cs''
                                   in (c : n ++ "." ++ m) : tokenize cs'''
                     _ -> (c : n) : tokenize cs'
  | c `elem` "+/*-()" = [c] : tokenize cs
  | otherwise = error $ "unexpected character " ++ show c
```

Here is in action:

```
ghci> tokenize "( (23.5+age) ∗ (20.99+adres))"
["(","(","23.5","+","age",")","*","(","20.99","+","adres",")",")"]
```

That said: I *strongly* recommend you either write a parsing monad (something like `data Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }`) so that you can write your parser monadically, or use an existing library/tool (see Alex and `megaparsec` in particular)